# When I making a dump in controller its size 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have my controller code like this:

```
system("PGUSER=#{ENV["DATABASE_USER"]} PGPASSWORD=#{ENV["DATABASE_PASSWORD"]} pg_dump db_name_#{ENV["RAILS_ENV"]} > /location/db_name_#{@backup.name}.dump")
```

When I run it in rails console in production its ok and dump is right, but when it called from controller dump creating with size of `0 bytes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution here [Rails rake tasks for dump & restore of PostgreSQL databases](https://gist.github.com/hopsoft/56ba6f55fe48ad7f8b90)

And I used it in controller with some minor changes:

```
system "RAILS_ENV=production rake db:dump"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who owns the process. Maybe the process which handles controller request doesn't have access to the target folder or rights for execution pg_dump.
Also need to review and compare ENV var values for both cases. Are you sure about rails env, it the same?

If you have a ssh access to the server, you can find the process and it owner...
Use bash command for it
`ps aux | grep -i passenger`
or
`ps aux | grep -i unicorn`
or
`ps aux | grep -i puma`
or
`cat ./tmp/pids/server.pid` (then you can find process by pid)

It's depend of which web server module do you use for your application...

Then you need grant write access for process owner on target folder. Use for it `chown`, `chmod`.

Also you can try use a hack for your command - use a `sudo` command with password inside your `system` call. **But I strongly don't recommend to do it for production!**

Example: `system("echo 'password' | sudo -S -k #{dump_command}")`